# `Alert` sometimes gives ridiculously small windows - how to fix this?

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

This happens with Oracle Java 10 as well as OpenJDK 10 & 11 with OpenJFX from Maven on Linux. More often than not, it turns out like this:

[image: The alert window]

I tried `setMinWidth` and `setMinHeight`, but these seem to make no difference at all. My code:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType/INFORMATION);
alert.setTitle("Testtitle");
alert.setContentText("Some example content text for an alert box.");
alert.getDialogPane.setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
alert.getDialogPane.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
alert.showAndWait();
```

This is being run on the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: Try using Oracle JDK8, from my experience 10 is kinda funky when it comes to javafx.

Comment: Try `alert.show()` see if it does the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem is solved with `Alert#setResizable` true

```
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Label("Test"), 600, 400);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.initOwner(stage);
            alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            alert.setTitle("Exit");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Do you want to exit?");
            alert.setResizable(true);
//            alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
            alert.showAndWait();
        });

        stage.setTitle("TestApp");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)

> OpenJFX 11

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>   Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
>   Release:        18.04
>   Codename:       bionic